# Encode strings by subtracting one from each character code

Tags: javascript, performance, strings, comparative-review, caesar-cipher

I currently have this encoding function which simply subtracts one from each character code:

```
String.fromCharCode.apply(null, text.split("").map(function(v) {
    return v.charCodeAt() - 1;
}));
```

E.g. `test` becomes `sdrs`.

I know that this function is silly because it isn't a strong encoding algorithm, but that's not my point. The problem is that it is slow and causes a stack overflow for large strings (~130.000 in length).

I tried a regexp but that's even slower:

```
text.replace(/./g, function(v) {
    return String.fromCharCode(v.charCodeAt() - 1);
});
```

I tested both on [jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/replacing-regexp-vs-map).

Currently, I'm executing a function for each character in both functions. How can I make a function that does the same thing as what these functions are doing, but executes faster without stack overflows?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try looping through it with a simple for loop:

```
var b = '';
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
{
   b += String.fromCharCode(a.charCodeAt(i) - 1)
}
return b;
```

Comment: Wow, that seems amazingly fast. More than 20 times as fast in fact. Thanks!